# Is there any API call or any kind of feedback to know whether data is actually sent through google analytics collect endpoint?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have settled my google tag manager as from the [guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart).

I have got in place a page that redirect just after the tag `gtm-load` is collected into the `dataLayer`. It's actually a "transition" page that should redirect instantaneously.

In this way I make sure `google-analytics.com/r/collect` is called, as I can see from the network ta of my browser, seems the only way to do so for an "instant redirect page".

However I need to test it from the `back-end` side.

Is there any way to have a feedback from Google Analytics about the data is actually sent? For example something like `google-analytics.com/get/data/lastEntry`, so that I can use a `restAPI` to check it out?

As far as I know, google analytics provide only metrics through a web page, and no actual data sent to. 
Moreover there are some Rest API [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/devguide) but they are only for configuration purpose.

Answer (score 2):

you might pass a JavaScript function as a `hitCallback` parameter of analytics `send` command and it will be called right after hit data were sent:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback
Here's an example of how to use it with GTM alongside another useful feature of `eventcallback`
https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/hitcallback-eventcallback/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is great, `hitCallback` and `eventcallback` seems proper solution within JavaScript in order to make sure `google-analytics/collect` is actually called. But still cannot find a good solution for the `back-end` test. Thank you anyway for that, I missed those from GTM documentation.

Comment: Another two things to keep noted. #1. There's no way.to check if the data were passed properly from the 'collect' endpoint other than 30X/200 responses. #2 the other possibility to send data to analytics and redirect safely is using 'beacon' transport that is not blocked by window upload

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport

Answer (score 0):

There is a [realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3) in Google Analytics, so what I have done for testing is to call my test URL with [utm campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) attached. Then I made a call to the realtime API and filtered by my custom campaign.

The realtime API is fairly limited (no session based values, obviously, you cannot test custom dimensions etc), but at least this tells you if your hit has registered in GA.

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads up, I will have a look on that. Maybe can be useful in my case or in the future.